# How to create an event on Fan pages and for Groups using the Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am able to create an event using the Facebook JavaScript SDK.
Now I want to create an event as the fan page creator. How can I do this? And how do I create an event for groups?

I am using the following code to create events:

```js
FB.api('/me/events', 'post', {
    name: "title",
    start_time: "start time",
    end_time: "end time",
    description: "description",
    location: "location"
}, function (resp) {

});
```

Comment: Replace your page id with the keyword me.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [Graph API > PAGE](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) doc :

> To perform the operation **as a Page**, and **not the current user**, you must use the **Page's access token**, **not the user access token** commonly used for reading Graph API objects. This access token can be retrieved by issuing an **HTTP GET to /USER_ID/accounts** with the **manage_pages** permission. This will return a list of Pages (including application profile Pages) to which the user has administrative access, along with access_tokens for those Pages.

Then, using the **Page access token** :

> You can create an event for a page by issuing an **HTTP POST** request to **PAGE_ID/events** with the **create_event** and **manage_pages** permissions.